# What is the real problem that nlog.config is deprecated, because it does not work in modern .NET?

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0, nlog

In the NLog 5 changelog, we can see below note

> Deprecated NLog.Config nuget-package 
> NLog.Config nuget-package will no longer be released.
>
> Impact: NLog.Config-nuget-package will no longer be compatible with latest NLog and should be removed.
>
> Reason: NLog.Config-nuget-package stopped working properly when Microsoft refactored the nuget-package-system to support <packagereference>. Microsoft disabled the ability for a nuget-package to inject a default NLog.config into the project directory when one didn’t exist. Instead it became overwrite always, so when deploying an application with dependency on NLog.config-nuget-package, then it would unexpectedly reset the NLog.config.
>
> Workaround: Manually create the NLog.config file and add it to the application-project. Manually add NLog.Schema-package for intellisense in NLog.config.

My question is about the *"Microsoft disabled the ability for a nuget-package to inject a default NLog.config into the project directory when one didn’t exist. Instead it became overwrite always, so when deploying an application with dependency on NLog.config-nuget-package, then it would unexpectedly reset the NLog.config."* sentences.

What is technical cause that Microsoft decide something like this? And is there any alternative approach to resolve this problem? (manual working is very bad practice in large projects and large teams.)

Comment: NLog-project is not in control what Microsoft-/Nuget-team has decided. See also: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4942 + https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2823